# Mockito call a method on a parameter of a mocked method

Tags: java, mockito

I am just starting with Mockito and I just want to do something like :

```
public class Test {     
    public void clearList(List l){
        doVeryLOOOONGDatabaseCallll();
        l.clear();
        return;
    }
}

/// ... 
Test test = mock(Test.class);
Mockito.when(test.clearList(any(List.class))).then( l => l.clear());
```

Have some hint to do the trick?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, I want to clear the list put in parameters when the method `clearList(List l)` is called.

Comment: Mock `doVeryLOOOONGDatabaseCallll()` not `clearList()`. Mocking isn't about changing behavior inside methods; it's making it so you don't need external dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Brian, but it is a static method, I just wanted to simplify the things. I can't mock it.

Comment: Fair enough - didn't have that information :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this should do it (not tested):

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        List<?> list = (List<?>) args[0];
        list.clear();
        return null;
    }
}).when(test).clearList(any(List.class));
```