# Mockito test java 8 lambda Consumer API

Tags: java, lambda, junit, mockito

I need to test a class that is using another interface as a dependency injection with a lambda Consumer.

```
@Builder
public class Interactor {

    private final Gateway gateway;

    void process(String message, Consumer<String> response){
        gateway.process(message, uuid -> {
            response.accept(uuid.toString());
        });
    }
}
```

The dependency is defined like so:

```
public interface Gateway {

    void process(String message, Consumer<UUID> uuid);
}
```

How would I mock the Gateway so I can provide a UUID value response to my test?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
@Test
void whillReturnTheInjectedUUIDValueTest() {

    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    Gateway gateway = Mockito.mock(Gateway.class);
    Mockito.when(gateway.process("ignored", uuid1 -> {return uuid;}));

    Interactor.builder().gateway(gateway).build().process("ignored", s -> {
        Assertions.assertEquals(uuid.toString(), s);
    });
}
```

How should I provide the return value to the consumer?

Comment: `Consumer ` has the  `void accept(T t);` method which doesn't have a return value. what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to mock the Gateway so I can provide a return lambda and a value, I can then test different conditions by mocking different results from calling the gateway. My example here is very simple, I avoided putting the full code

Comment: to clearify, I have to method calls that return void and get a Consumer lambda. One call the other. How can I provide the inner lambda to my mocked inner interface?

Comment: Is `any(Consumer.class)` not enough?

Comment: How do I provide the inner consumer with value?

Comment: But you really only have to verify that hatte way and the consumer are called from the process method...

Answer (score 4):

this one did the trick

```
@Test
void willReturnTheInjectedUUIDValueTest() {

    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    Gateway gateway = Mockito.mock(Gateway.class);

    doAnswer(ans -> {
        Consumer<UUID> callback = (Consumer<UUID>) ans.getArgument(1);
        callback.accept(uuid);
        return null;
    }).when(gateway).process(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(Consumer.class));

    Interactor.builder().gateway(gateway).build().process("ignored", s -> {
        Assertions.assertEquals(uuid.toString(), s);
    });
}
```

This answer was the hint -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226374/148397

Answer (score 1):

For now I ended up mocking my own inner class without Mockito.

```
class InteractorTest {

    @Test
    void whillReturnTheInjectedUUIDValueTest() {

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

        Gateway gateway = GatewayMock.builder().value(uuid).build();

        Interactor.builder().gateway(gateway).build().process("ignored", s -> {
            Assertions.assertEquals(uuid.toString(), s);
        });
    }

    @Builder
    private static class GatewayMock implements Gateway {

        private final UUID value;

        @Override
        public void process(String message, Consumer<UUID> uuid) {
            uuid.accept(value);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## What you want...

is to verify the result of the logic of `Interactor#process`, which takes a `Consumer<String>` and basically just calls `Gateway#process` with a `Consumer<UUID>` implementation that calls back to the `Consumer<String>` parameter.

Ideally you want to do this just by calling `Interactor#process` and verifying the call to the `Consumer<String>` you supply.

## Your problem is...

that it is up to the implementator of `Gateway` to trigger the `Consumer<UUID>` (and consequently the `Consumer<String>`).  So you need to inject an implementation of `Gateway` that does just that.

## The solution is...

along the lines of the answer you provided (i.e. using a Fake Object instead of a Mock), unless there is a real implementation of `Gateway` in your production code that you can easily use instead (but I assume you'd be doing that already if that was the case).

Can you do it with Mockito?  Sure, you can call methods on a mock object's method arguments, as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819818/775138 - but why would you go there if you can provide a sufficient `Gateway` implementation in a single line:

```
Gateway gw = (message, consumer) -> consumer.accept(uuid);
```

where `uuid` is the UUID instance that you constructed before.  So no need to declare a static inner class just for this.

## However...

there is an important issue with your assertion: if `Interactor` does nothing at all instead of calling the `Gateway`, the `Consumer<String>` you provide (containing the assertion) won't get triggered, so your test will pass!  Just assign the value to a member variable of your test class, and assert on that outside the lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @herman. The gateway API will have more than one method so your consumer function will not work unfortiunatly. I do need a full mocked object. I didn't see how the example link is related to my question.